# Mysql script for web based program

Tags: mysql

I have a web based inventory database setup such that when a new purchase order(PO) is inserted it also inserts into the PO table as well as the stocks table. My stocks table looks like this:

```
Stock_ID | Date | PO_ID | DR_ID | Product_ID | Stock_In | Stock_Out | Stock_Balance |
```

and my PO table looks like this:

```
PO_ID | Supplier_ID | Date | Product_ID | Quantity | Unit | Unit Price | Total Amount |
```

I need a sql script so that when I add a new PO the Stock Balance field is automatically adjusted.

Stock_ID and PO_ID are auto-increment.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at triggers: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Something like this perhaps:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_stockBalance BEFORE INSERT ON PurchaseOrders
  UPDATE Stocks 
  SET Stock_Balance = Stock_Balance + NEW.quantity
  WHERE PO_ID = NEW.PO_ID
```

Comment: I don't think triggers are the answer because I want to get the last recorded value of the stock balance. Let's say that product 7 has a stock balance of 2000. Now when I insert a new PO, I want the quantity to add to the previous stock balance to get the new stock balance. Product 7's new stock balance would be whatever quantity I entered in the PO + the previous stock balance.

Comment: @DarkXaldin so use a trigger that calls a stored procedure

Comment: Try my example and let us know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

First, why don't you separate your stock in 3 simple parts as follow:

```
stock_entry
stock_output
stock_balance
```

and in your **stock table** you do not need the *product id*, since it come from **PO table** right?

Personally I prefer to control the quantity in my **product table**, also I have the **stock_entry** and stock_output to sum up my balance and then **UPDATE** the quantity in my **product table** (field quantity).

But of course I do not know what approach did you take in your data model.

> Stock Balance field is automatically
>   adjusted

to auto adjust the balance you need to check **income** and **outcome** **stock** and I think the best approach is to separate things ....   otherwise you can get a lot of mess in your balance.

Comment: I actually followed a company's stock card as the requirement for my project is to base the table on the company's stock card, so I can't change the fields.

Comment: @DarkXaldin I understood perfectly. No problem, maybe you can try UPDATE fields in your stock_table based in your PK, something like PO was made, then you insert a new line to your stock_table, but I think is a hard to control way when everything is together, 'cause in somewhere you will need to tell your table to list only the last register that was input and the balance must be right.. I did some weeks ago the same what you are trying now, and change all the data model, because this approach was so hard to me, and return data loss to me.. you just need a lot of verification on script side.